# update table according to query result

Tags: php, mysql, join, left-join

I have 2 tables

```
table 1                        and    table 2 
user_id     subtotal                  user_id    section1_id         section2_id          
1              10                       1            1                   0
2              5                        2            1                   1
1              4                        3            1                   1
3              6                        4            1                   2
3              6                        5            1                   2
4              0                        6            1                   3
5              0                        7            1                   3
6              0                        8            2                   2
7              0
8              0
```

I did the next query to to sort table2.user_id according to sum of table1.subtotal putting in consideration where table2_section1id = 1

```
    SELECT table2.user_id, table2.section1_id, table2.section2_id, SUM( table1.subtotal ) AS total_price
    FROM table1
    LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.user_id = table2.user_id
    AND table2.section1_id =1
    GROUP BY table2.user_id
    ORDER BY total_price DESC
```

I got the next result

```
table2.user_id        table2.section1_id        table2.section2_id           total_price
    1                        1                         0                        14
    3                        1                         1                         6
    2                        1                         1                         5
    4                        1                         2                         0
    5                        1                         2                         0
    6                        1                         3                         0
    7                        1                         3                         0
```

now I need to update table2.section2_id fileds according to the sort of this query to be the next :

```
table2.section2_id
0                    first field to be = 0
1                    second field to be = table2.user_id first field value
1                    third field to be = table2.user_id first field value
1                    forth field to be = table2.user_id first field value
3                    fifth field to be = table2.user_id second field value
3                    sixth field to be = table2.user_id second field value
3                    seventh field to be = table2.user_id second field value
if there are more rows lets continue 
2                    eighth field to be = table2.user_id third field value
2                    ninth field to be = table2.user_id third field value
2                    tenth field to be = table2.user_id third field value
4                    eleventh field to be = table2.user_id forth field value
4                    twelfth field to be = table2.user_id forth field value
4                    thirteenth field to be = table2.user_id forth field value
```

and thus till finished all rows

please advice